# Activity adjustResize not working

Tags: android

I have a problem with resizing of my `Activity` layout with `softInputMode="adjustResize"`. It is not actually resizing and I don't see the part of my multiline text is under the keyboard. If I use only `softInputMode="adjustPan"`, without `adjustResize`, layout moved up to the input position but my `fab` is under the keyboard. Here my layout hierarchy:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <requestFocus/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

      <!-- Some another content -->

      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/feedback"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:minLines="10"/>
      </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
      android:layout_margin="@dimen/support_fab_margin"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_send"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

PS: If I remove collapsing toolbar everithing works fine. But I need collapsing toolbar (((

Answer (score 1):

Try to This way. It's Working for me.

**Activity** (after setcontentView):

this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

**AndroidMenifest.xml**(Activity which contains EditText) :

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize".

Comment: This should hide soft keyboard. How does it help?